# Saving Button location in XML file in Windows Form

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

My problem is Saving Button location in XML file. My Form have button that are draggable on edit form, so when i am finished editing the form i want to save Button location in XML file, so then i can read the location from the XML file and display the button on the modified position.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Can't You just read Button.Top and Button.Left properties and save them in xml ?

Comment: So just save the locations of your buttons in an xml file. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Is your problem to create & || read an XML file?

Comment: Your question is too broad and it's unclear what the problem is. Please edit your question to follow the suggestions in the [ask] page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's otherwise a requirement for your application or you need to store additional complex data, you don't really need to create an XML file. You could use a plain text file like this:

```
var fileContents = string.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n", button.Top, button.Left);
File.WriteAllText("ButtonCoordinates.dat");
```

Then to read and apply back the coordinates:

```
var fileContents = File.ReadAllLines("ButtonCoordinates.dat");
button.Top = double.Parse(fileContents[0]);
button.Left = double.Parse(fileContents[1]);
```

Of course you need to add error checking, file path management et al, but you get the idea.